# Dúvida sobre erro else without a previuos if, em comunicação serial entre dois arduinos

Tags: arduino

Estou fazendo uma comunicação, serial no simulador tinkercad, entre dois arduino, o meu codigo está apresentado, erro:

> else without a previuos if

A ideia do programar é pressionar botão, no arduino emissor é acender led no emissor e segundo led , no outro arduino, receptor por comunicação serial..

Arduino emissor

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(11,INPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if(digitalRead(11)){
   digitalWrite(10,1);
   Serial.println(255);
  }
  else{
   digitalWrite(10,0);
   Serial.println(0);
  }
  delay(100);

}
```

Arduino receptor

```
void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(8,INPUT);
  pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
  int value;
}

void loop() {
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    int value = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println(value);


    if ( value == 255);{
        digitalWrite(10,1);


    }else {
      digitalWrite(10,0);  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: O erro está no seu código `if ( value == 255);{` veja o `;` em local incorreto.

Comment: vlw! Celso era isso msm, quebrando a cabeça com coisa besta! obrigado